# Grails external jar is not being inclued

Tags: grails-3.0

I am totally new to grails framework. I am having trouble including the external jar files to grails project.

My lib location is: Project -> lib

Build.config

```
  dependencies {
    compile fileTree (dir: './lib', include: ['*.jar'])
    runtime fileTree (dir: './lib', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Could someone please guide me on this

Answer (score 0):

Try `fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')`

Comment: This resolve the runtime dependency but when i am using that classes inside groovy ..eg ..import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver ..classes are not resolved ...compile fileTree (dir: './lib', include: ['*.jar'])  runtime fileTree (dir: './lib', include: ['*.jar']) ..I have tried in  different way ...

Comment: This problem has been solved. I have added the external jar from the project model and set the scope as provided and it worked